# Error, when I'm initializing IE browser using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

When I initialize IE browser using Selenium C#,

```
 case BrowserType.InternetExplorer:
                     IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\Program Files\\internet
 explorer\\iexplore.exe");
                     driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
                    //InternetExplorerOptions options2= new InternetExplorerOptions();
                    // options2. = ("C:\\Program Files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe");
                     //DriverContext.Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                     //DriverContext.Browser = new Browser(DriverContext.Driver);
                    // DriverContext.Browser.Maximize();
                  break;
```

I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. TearDown : System.NullReferenceException :
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi @mjwills,I'm trying to trigger the IE browser and run my code which works fine in Chrome n FIrefox. Below is the bit of code I used:
  
                case BrowserType.Firefox:
                    FirefoxOptions options1 = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options1.BrowserExecutableLocation = ("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

Comment: case BrowserType.Firefox:
                    FirefoxOptions options1 = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options1.BrowserExecutableLocation = ("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine
                    DriverContext.Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    DriverContext.Browser = new Browser(DriverContext.Driver);
                    DriverContext.Browser.Maximize();
                    break;

Comment: Is it row `driver.Navigate()...` that throws the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the available code the only thing which jumps out to me is that you are specifying the location of IE. I would drop this and allow the webdriver to use the default location. I've never had to specify path with IE. I don't think it's possible for it to be in an alternate location.

Comment: I dropped the path. Still the same error           case BrowserType.InternetExplorer:
                    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    DriverContext.Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    DriverContext.Browser = new Browser(DriverContext.Driver);
                    DriverContext.Browser.Maximize();
                    break;

Comment: Can you post the entire class used?